# Binning for a histogram in python

Tags: python, histogram, binning

I have a text files with two columns something like this

```
0      0.0 \
1      2.4800279266728324e-06\
2      9.823187699026918e-06\
3      2.1883453405001393e-05\
4      3.8513895910245685e-05\
5      5.9566616657733786e-05\
6      8.489267671382621e-05\
7      0.0001143420206179056\
8      0.0001477633945415465\
9      0.00018500425820479948\
10     0.00022591068993023063\
11     0.00027032728413800794\
12     0.000318097040494579\ 
13     0.00036906124381725773\
14     0.00042305933368967896\
```

I want to do a construct a histogram where each bins hava a width of 100 keV. How to do this coding in Python.

I tried to do the binning by taking the maximum and minimum value and divide them by the number of bins, but I think I am doing it wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77847435/edit) your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [full text of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a bin width (100 in your case) in advance, then you can do

```
assigned_bin = math.floor((max - min) / bin_width)
```

to choose which bin each observation goes in.